# Matlab error when executed clear command using mexCallMATLAB in mex file

Tags: c, matlab

The code which executed prompts to  error is:

```
 void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
 {
    double p;
    p  =   (double)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1, prhs, "clear");

 }
```

Where I am trying to clear a variable which is in workspace pointed by prhs[0].
Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Error message when executed this function with one argument. gives following error message:

> > callmatlabtest(10)
> >     ??? Error using ==> clear
> >     Argument must contain a string.

Comment: Please see my solution below. Your code above is calling `clear` on `prhs` which is a pointer *array*, not a pointer to the name of the variable you are trying to clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to have `&prhs[0]` in your call:

```
mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 1, &prhs[0], "clear");
```

I've tested this code and it works (in a file named mextest.c):

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
  mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1, &prhs[0], "clear");
}
```

and here is the result:

```
>> a = 10;
>> who
Your variables are:
a  
>> mextest('a')
>> who
>>
```

Comment: You are right, I changed it. still it crashes! I don't know why. Following is the code: #include"mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double p = 100;
    prhs[0] = &p;
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1, prhs, "clear");

}

Comment: &prhs[0] and prhs are the same thing, no?

Comment: Your code in your comment above is not doing the same thing that I've suggested. Your are just creating a local variable `p` in your code and trying to call `clear` on it!

Answer (score 1):

Callmatlabtest(10) is the same as clear(10), since callmatlabtest just forwards its own inputs to clear (via mexCallMATLAB). The clear function expects a string input, and 10 is a double, hence the error message "argument must contain a string".